# How to forecast future numbers using Random Forest Regressor in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, random-forest

I'm trying to forecast future numbers of coronavirus cases using RandomForestRegressor but it gives me this kind of error when I tried to execute it:

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-181-c9a9a8208098> in <module>()
      1 test_data = np.arange(260, 367).reshape(-1, 1)
----> 2 rf_regressor_fit_future = rf_regressor.fit(test_data, target)
      3 forecast_rf_future = rf_regressor_fit_future.predict(test_data)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    263         if len(y) != n_samples:
    264             raise ValueError("Number of labels=%d does not match "
--> 265                              "number of samples=%d" % (len(y), n_samples))
    266         if not 0 <= self.min_weight_fraction_leaf <= 0.5:
    267             raise ValueError("min_weight_fraction_leaf must in [0, 0.5]")

ValueError: Number of labels=259 does not match number of samples=107
```

This is the code I use to create future days and forecast using the samples:

```
test_data = np.arange(260, 367).reshape(-1, 1)
rf_regressor_fit_future = rf_regressor.fit(test_data, target)
forecast_rf_future = rf_regressor_fit_future.predict(test_data)
```

The dataset has only 259 days and samples, and forecasting actual data runs well. But I'm having problems for the future days. What should I do to solve this error by matching the number of samples? Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Random Forest is almost certainly unsuitable for projecting future cases of Coronavirus. The maximum number of cases it can predict is the maximum number of cases within the training dataset. It is therefore of almost zero value for predicting exponentially growing cases numbers. Please use a more suitable method.

Comment: Thank you, Robert. This is noted. I wanted to know how can I predict future dates using it? is there any parameters can I use to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Random Forest Regression is not suitable for such tasks. I have done a similar project but I have used Polynomial Regression. If you like, you can check it out here:

https://github.com/sanyogthescholar/covid_19

Comment: I wanted to try, is there any way or parameters so I can predict future values with future dates? using Random Forest Regression?